# HTTP 404 error in my first Struts2 application

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I have made a simple struts 2 application for my learning purpose. I have followed the tutorial from youtube. But after completing my program, when I run it, it is showing HTTP 404 error when I enter the URL: `http://localhost:1443/Struts2Example/hello.action`.

Following is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
<display-name>Struts2Example</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

<filter>
<filter-name>Struts2</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>Struts2</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Following is my Action Class

```
package com.subir.struts2.action;

public class getAction {

public String execute()
{

    System.out.println("Hello !execute method ");

   System.out.println("Hello from get getAction!!");
   return "success";
}

}
```

Following is my struts.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true"></constant>
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="hello" class="com.subir.struts2.action.getAction">
        <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

Following is my success.jsp

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
Success Page!!!
</body>
</html>
```

Following is my error.jsp

```
  <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

  <html>
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
 <title>Insert title here</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 Error page!!!
 </body>
 </html>
```

Following is my directory structure.

[image]

Please let me know what might be the issue causing this error.

Comment: @AndreaLigios apache 8.0.28

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1- In your `web.xml` you have to close `</web-app>`

2- In your `struts.xml` you have to close `</struts>`

3- you must add struts 2 Deploy path in Web Deployment Assembly in Eclipse like in this picture
[image]

NB: the first letter in  class name in JAVA it should be uppercase letter instead of `class getAction` you should use `class GetAction` or other name which starts with uppercase letter.

I tested your code with my configuration `struts 2.3.24`, `Tomcat 8.0`, `jdk 1.8`, with those rectification, it work without problems.

[image]

In console

[image]

Comment: Hi , I missed `webapp` and `struts` tags here, however I used them in my code. The only change I have done was using `WEB_INF/lib` in deployment assembly. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Mistu4u remember it's WEB-INF, not WEB_INF, just in case

Comment: @AndreaLigios Thanks for the comment. However I have one query: what does point number 3 in this answer do? I did not understand it. In fact, I have not used this method in any of my servlet programs I did earlier.

Comment: Neither did I. The last time I've used an IDE to build a WAR it was JBuilder, in 2004 :D then Ant+Ivy, then Maven (nowadays THE standard, no matter what Ant and Gradle fanboys say). The important thing is only the result: you need to produce a valid WAR, no matter how. If you start messing with files and directory, good luck with that :)