# Having HTTP 404 status code with my first Struts2 project

Tags: java, struts2

I have encountered HTTP 404 status code issue with my first Struts2 project. I have tried bunch of approaches but still no get the problem solved.Can anyone please check my code and project structure if there is any mistake?

- Eclipse Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)
- struts-2.3.32
- jdk1.8.0_131
- apache-tomcat-8.0.43

**Project Explorer:**

[image]

**struts.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
   "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
   <package name="helloworld" extends="struts-default">

      <action name="index">
            <result >/index.jsp</result>
      </action>

      <action name="hello" 
            class="com.tutorialspoint.struts2.HelloWorldAction" 
            method="execute">
            <result name="success">/HelloWorld.jsp</result>
      </action>

   </package>
</struts>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
   xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
   id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

   <display-name>Struts 2</display-name>
   <welcome-file-list>
      <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>
   <filter>
      <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
      <filter-class>
        org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
      </filter-class>
   </filter>

   <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
   <h1>Hello World From Struts2</h1>
   <form action="hello">
      <label for="name">Please enter your name</label><br/>
      <input type="text" name="name"/>
      <input type="submit" value="Say Hello"/>
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**HelloWorld.jsp**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
   Hello World, <s:property value="name"/>
</body>
</html>
```

**HelloWorldAction.java**

```
package com.tutorialspoint.struts2;

public class HelloWorldAction{
   private String name;

   public String execute() throws Exception {
      return "success";
   }

   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }
}
```

[image]

**Online solution I have tried:**

[HTTP 404 error in my first Struts2 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33619150/http-404-error-in-my-first-struts2-application)

This one is pretty similar with my issue,but it is not helping me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import jar package `commons-lang3-x.x.jar` instead of `commons-lang-x.x.jar`

Comment: Still not working with your URL. Jsp files are at the same level as `WEB-INF` and `META-INF`.I am in a really awkward situation now.

Comment: I just notice you are using `commons-lang-2.4.jar`. It should be `commons-lang3-3.2.jar`

Comment: Wooow! You made my day! It is working with `commons-lang3-3.2.jar`. Could you please explain what is the difference between these two versions of `commons-lang` packages?

Comment: You may check it here [Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/article3_0.html)

Comment: OK thank you very much. I have edited your answer, you may accept it or edit by yourself.

Answer (score -1):

You have missed your package name. Can you try with below URL "http://localhost:8080/HelloWorldStruts2/helloworld/index.action"

Comment: I tried this, it was not working.

Comment: Do you know why we keep it below config?? <package name="helloworld" extends="struts-default">

      <action name="index">
            <result >/index.jsp</result>
      </action>

Comment: I have tried to run the project without `<action name="index"> <result >/index.jsp</result> </action>` in the `struts.xml` file and `<welcome-list-file>` in the `web.xml`. I came to conclusion that you are not supposed to have these configurations as long as you have put `index.jsp` file at the right directory.